# Get amount of references to an Object at runtime

Tags: java, pointers, dictionary, reference

Is it possible to see how many references there are currently to an Object?

**Situation**
I have instances of `Map.Entry` stored in references other than their `Map`, so I can keep them where I need them and directly access the values without constantly checking for the mapping to its key.

I want the references to be updated to changed to the `Map`. They won't if I use `Map.get(key)`.

There are problems with that however...
If an `Entry` is removed, it could still exist in references which would still return the value. Though, I could choose to never remove, but set them to `null`, to overcome that.

However, I'm worried the above would cause the memory to be filled with a huge amount of `null` entries over time, should there be a lot of temporary unique keys used, like dates.

I figured if there was a way to get the amount of references to a `Map.Entry` with the value `null`, if it'd be `1`, then that would be the one in the `Map`, meaning there are no other references, so it's safe to remove the `Entry`. And otherwise, if there are other references, it should remain and still return `null`.

Is there such possibility?

Comment: Are you inventing a garbage collector?

Comment: What do you mean by "the memory to be filled with a huge amount of null"?

Comment: @Sleiman Map.Entry objects with the value being null

Comment: And how would this fill the memory?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with `constantly checking the map`. If you are using a `HashMap`, `map.get()` and `map.containsKey()` are basically free, so holding on to `Map.Entry` objects (and potentially creating memory leaks) in order to avoid this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I want the references to be updated to changes to the Map, they won't if I use get(key). And I don't want to use get(key) in the code because that's slow.

Comment: @Myst Why is `get(key)` slow? Which implementation of `Map` are you using?

Comment: `HashMap`. It depends on the size of the `Map` and the usage of course

Comment: @Myst That's true. If you are using a huge `HashMap` with lots of entries in the same bucket, it could be a problem, but unless you have *very* good reason to think you need to hold on to extra references to `Map.Entry` objects, I would not do it.

Comment: I chose to do so because they would be updated to changes to their value and they would skip the key-checking as well, however, cause the above problem

Answer (score 2):

Java memory management does not work that way. Nothing is keeping track of the number of references to an object.

It sounds like your real problem is that you don't have a good model of the lifecycle of your objects. If something is retrieving `Map.Entry` objects and holding on to the references beyond when they would otherwise have been collected, then *that's* where the leak lies. You should probably use a memory profiler (I've found [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/) useful for this purpose, but there are others) to determine what is filling up memory.

They're about C#, not Java, but the points in these blog posts apply to your situation as well:

- [How do I get the reference count of a CLR object?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100811-00/?p=13173)
- [How can I find all objects of a particular type?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100812-00/?p=13163)
- [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203/)

Comment: Could you have misunderstood the question? It is not about memory leaks / garbage collection.

Comment: Do you recommend moving away from referencing entries and look for another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: @Myst: Your question is somewhat unclear and it's entirely possible I misunderstood it. But fundamentally I stand by my answer: your problem appears to be that you don't have a good model of the lifecycle of your objects. If you find that your application is using more memory than expected, I would definitely use a memory profiler to understand what's going on. You need to provide more data about the problem before we can help you make a decision about the right solution, but I'm pretty certain that anything based on "getting the amount of references" is the wrong solution.

Comment: I want references to Objects in the Map and have them be updated with changes to the Map. Both can be achieved by referencing the Entry instead. However they won't be aware of removal from the Map, and setting the value to null won't free the memory.

Comment: @Myst: Then you should just look up from the map again each time you need the value rather than holding a reference to a `Map.Entry` object which might get orphaned. If your problem is that `get()` is too slow, that's almost certainly because of the implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` for the key objects you're using. That's what you should fix.